# Store checkbox value to Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app and I need to register user. I also have two checkboxes where the user selects gender (male or female). I know that checkbox understand boolean values true or false, but I'm wondering how to do that with firebase.
This is exactly what I need to do:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ik8w.png)

Here what I've done:

```
private void SignUp(final String firstName, final String lastName, final String email, final String password, final String checkMale, final String checkFemale) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
          if(task.isSuccessful()) {
               FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
               assert user != null;
               String userId =user.getUid();

               reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
               HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
               hashMap.put("id", userId);
               hashMap.put("firstName", firstName);
               hashMap.put("lastName", lastName);
               hashMap.put("email", email.toLowerCase());
               if(male.isChecked() && female.isChecked()) {
                   hashMap.put("male", checkMale);
                   hashMap.put("female", checkFemale);
               }
               reference.setValue(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
          if(task.isSuccessful()) {
               pd.dismiss();
               Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
               intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               startActivity(intent);
               Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
          }
     });
     } else {
          pd.dismiss();
          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You can't register with this email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
      }
   });
 }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to pass the Male or Female text based on the selected checkbox right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Radio Buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton#java)** instead of checkbox.

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/malleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Male"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/femaleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Female"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

And in code you can check which is selected.

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.maleButton:
            if (checked)
                hashMap.put("male", true);
            break;
        case R.id.femaleButton:
            if (checked)
                hashMap.put("male", false);
            break;
    }
}
```

Also you do not need to store 2 variables in firebase male and female if users can choose only one. In other case(if users can choose both) store 2 variables and remove radiogroup so users can choose both.

Comment: True, you should use a `RadioGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

I think in gender both can't checked at once and you kept && condition, so I would't work here:

```
 if(male.isChecked() && female.isChecked()) {
                    hashMap.put("male", checkMale);
                    hashMap.put("female", checkFemale);
 }
```

First of all do not need to save both value male & female. Just keep once key "gender" and specify one string or number e.g. 1 or "m" for male & 2 or "f" for female and save it along with all value.

Here you can use RadioButton inside RadioGroup 'gender' instead of only RadioButtons.

For your reference:

```
if(male.isChecked())
      hashMap.put("gender", "m");
else
      hashMap.put("gender", "f");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Radio Buttons in place of the checkbox.

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/rdgGender"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/rbMale"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Male"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/rbFemale"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Female"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

get RadioGroup id

```
RadioGroup rdgGender = findViewbyId(R.id.rdgGender);
```

on submit button click

```
public void onSubmitClick() {
boolean checkedId = rdgGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

switch(checkedId) {
    case R.id.rbMale:
            hashMap.put("gender", "Male");
        break;
    case R.id.rbFemale:
            hashMap.put("gender", "Female");
        break;
}
}
```